# Calculating page numbers and offsets

Tags: offset

Let's say we have 1kb pages (2^10). The address is 512. To find the number of pages we do:

512/1024 = 0.5 (therefore it's on page 1)

To find the offset we do (address - (page*page_size)):

512 - (1*1024) = -512

A negative offset is not possible, is it?

Comment: Or should it be page 0 offset 512?

Comment: This is just one example of why some programming languages index from zero. Further reading. Edsger W. Dijkstra's "Why should numbering start at zero" http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your address is in page 0, not page 1.  You are correct that a negative offset is not possible.

Comment: Doh, I just realized a moment ago. I feel silly. So the page is 0 and offset is 512?